# How to import content from Excel file into Database by Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project where I should be able to import an excel file and read the contents then upload the information to the database via Laravel 5.2

an Example content like this

```
____________________________________________________
No.  |  Title   |   Type  |  Authorize . ..
____________________________________________________
 1.  |  AAAA    |   $     |  Admin, Manager, Co-Worker
 2.  |  BBBB    |   %     |  Manager, Co-Worker
 3.  |  AESR    |   %     |  Manager
 4.  |  MYTH    |   $     |  Co-Worker
                . . . . .
___________________________________________________
  Period | 2 times / year
____________________________________________________
```

now I don't know about that contents. but **I want to know some guide or an example for **Laravel 5.2****

Finally, I'm sorry for my bad English and hope someone can read it and guide for me. (I'm new for Laravel)
Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You may want to review the following link before asking further questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. You can try this package http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import

Comment: @haakym thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library/package which is easy to use and configure and it has some tutorials too.

[Laravel Excel v2.1.* for Laravel 5](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

Comment: Glad that helped you.